# C#: put many Json inside m solution for future use

Tags: c#, json

So i have [this](https://github.com/pbakondy/mcc-mnc-list/blob/master/mcc-mnc-list.json) `Json` list.

I want to put this list inside my solution and from time to time just ask for specific country and get all its `Json` with all its parameters (also not all the parameters required)

Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: "I want to put this list inside my solution"...you mean store the JSON file in the solution and use C# code to read from it? You'd 1) put the file into your project somewhere. 2) read the data from the file as a single string, 3) serialise it to a C# object (or list of objects, since it's an array of JSON). You can cheat by using `dynamic` or have a concrete class to match the structure precisely, 4) use maybe something like linq to find specific items within the list. The logic isn't too hard...all these steps are very well documented online...what's stopping you from trying this yourself?

Comment: Do you want to include this file in your dll as a resource, or be able to change the file on the file system and have your program recognize the changes?

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty simple object. The easiest way is to convert that to a C# object, and just include that in your solution, rather than storing it as a raw JSON object and parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
As @ADyson said in his comment there is lot of documentation out there to help you educate and implement the scenario you mentioned. 

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

//Creating a Class object with all the properties of json string
public class CountriesInfo
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string countryName { get; set; }
    public string countryCode { get; set; }
    public string mcc { get; set; }
    public string mnc { get; set; }
    public string brand { get; set; }
    public string @operator { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string bands { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
}

  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var strCountriesList = File.ReadAllText(@"YourJSONFilePath");

        JArray countriesInfoListArray = JArray.Parse(strCountriesList);

        List<CountriesInfo> countriesInfoList = countriesInfoListArray.Select(p => new CountriesInfo()
        {
            type = (string) p["type"],
            countryName = (string) p["countryName"],
            countryCode = (string) p["countryCode"],
            mcc = (string) p["mcc"],
            mnc = (string) p["mnc"],
            brand = (string) p["brand"],
            @operator = (string) p["@operator"],
            status = (string) p["status"],
            bands = (string) p["bands"],
            notes = (string) p["notes"]

        }).ToList();

       // Filters the countries based on the countryName (since the country name has null I am checking for null in countryName
        var filteredCountries =  countriesInfoList.Where(p => p.countryName != null && p.countryName.Equals("CountryYouWantToFilter"));

        foreach (var countryInfo in filteredCountries)
        {
           //do something with the countryInfo as shown below
            var strOperator = countryInfo.@operator;
            var status = countryInfo.status; 
        }
```